# How to get the length of the json object?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, aem

I wrote the ajax it gives me the json data in the console of my browser like this
[image: Output in the console]

This is my code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(function() {
       var searchUrl = "http://localhost:4502/bin/typeaHeadServelt";
       console.log("CONSOLE WORKING");
    $(".search").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({

                 url:"http://localhost:4502/bin/typeaHeadServelt",
                 dataType: 'json',
                   data:{term: request.term},
                    success: function(data)
                   {   

                      console.log(data);

                   },
                    error: function (data)
                   {
                        console.log("error");
                    }
            });
        }
    });
 });
})
```

**console.log(data)** gives me the above output.But how to get the length of the json object.

I tried like Object.keys(data[0]).length;
But it always returns the answer as 2 .
How can I get the length?

Comment: `data.length` ?

Comment: What do you expect, there are 2 keys in the each of the object inside the array you are getting. Do you want the length of the array?

Comment: yes I want the length of the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the output in the console you'll see that data is an array.

To get the length of an array you can simply use.

```
var length = data.length
```

In case data would be an object and you want to see how many keys are present. Then you'll use.

```
var length = Object.keys(data).length;
```

---

**In your example:**

If you use `data.length`, it will return `5` as your array has the length of 5.

If you use `Object.keys(data[0]).length`, it will return `2` as you have two items *(name and location)* in the first array element.

More information on arrays and objects can be found below.

[MND - Array's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)
[MDN - Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Answer (score 1):

you can use `data.length` in order to get number of results is returned by the server.

Answer (score 1):

```
let jsObject = {'name':'Kasun', 'address':'columbo','age': '29'};
```

let num = Object.keys(jsObject).length;
console.log(num);